# Mock fields of inner static class with easyMock

Tags: java, unit-testing, easymock

Is it possible to mock public fields of inner static class

```
public class SysConfig {

    public static class PackageConfig {
        public boolean checked;
    }

}
```

I want to mock "checked" field of PackageConfig class.

NOTE: I can't use powermock because i want to find coverage of code and powermock is causing some problems with it.

Answer (score 0):

Since it's a public boolean...you could...set the value :P

Other than that, we'll need some context - how do you intend on using the mock?

P.S. As far as I know, Powermock should only give you issues with code coverage if you're mocking the class under test.

Comment: Actually its default constructor is private and object can only be initialised through a factory method which has complex implementation.